# In what year and in which Bitcoin improvement proposal Opcodes such as OP_MODE have been disabled?

Tags: script, bip, opcodes

On [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) several opcodes are listed as "disabled".

My question is simple: which Bitcoin improvement proposal proposed to disable them, and when they have effectively been disabled in the past?

I'm particularly interested in the OP_MOD arithmetic opcode.

---

Answer (score 1):

It appears many unused opcodes were disabled in 2010 for security reasons (at least OP_CAT) or as a security precaution (many others).

[Pseudonymous](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/24925/pseudonymous) commented that the first BIPs didn't start until 2011 - a year later.